# Crash when use weak obj in block

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block

My code is like this:

```
Member *member = [Member new];
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self
member.gotoPageBlock = ^(NSString *url) {
    __strong __typeof(weakSelf) self = weakSelf
    [self goToPageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
};
```

It would crash rarely and the top stack of this crash is like this:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x365722298
Triggered by Thread:  0
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182794bb4 _objc_loadWeakRetained :156 (in libobjc.A.dylib)
```

The crash occurs when executing the block.
Is there anyone know what happened?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as is. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making strong self again is not needed so, remove this line `__strong __typeof(weakSelf) self = weakSelf` and then should work properly

Use this

```
Member *member = [Member new];
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self
member.gotoPageBlock = ^(NSString *url) {
    //the difference is here
    [weakSelf goToPageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
};
```

check this https://sectionfive.net/blog/2014/11/24/arc-exploration-and-pitfalls/ in the **Losing ownership while executing** section for further information

Comment: Maybe that's a solution，but I want to know why this crash happen.

Comment: @user3016644 check this https://sectionfive.net/blog/2014/11/24/arc-exploration-and-pitfalls/ in the **Losing ownership while executing** section for further information

Comment: What happens if you have two `weakSelf` calls inside the block?

Comment: There is no semantic difference between this and the OP's code

Comment: @newacct are you sure? read it again the OP is making `self` strong inside the block

Comment: @ReinierMelian: They make a strong reference inside the block and use that strong reference to make the call. But that's exactly what happens in your code too -- whenever you use a weak reference in a statement, ARC makes a temporary strong reference for the duration of that statement

Comment: yes but the problem is that my code don't crash and OP's code crashes @newacct which is a big difference, is not the same ARC making a strong temporal reference to some object and what OP is doing

Comment: @ReinierMelian: There is no difference. The compiled binary is the same in both cases. The OP said his code crashes "rarely". Your code, if plugged in, will crash "rarely" in exactly the same way.